# vsts-npm-auth is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: node.js, npm, azure-devops

First I run **npm install -g vsts-npm-auth** command and I get a message that vsts-npm-auth@0.41.0 installed.
But then when I'm running vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc command I get the following error message:

---

vsts-npm-auth : The term 'vsts-npm-auth' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (vsts-npm-auth:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: Are you on windows or MacOS/Linux? Macos requires a different setup. See [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops#linux-or-mac)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since you mentioned the package `vsts-npm-auth` has been installed successfully, but still encountered the "The term 'vsts-npm-auth' is not recognized" error. It's likely that the **npm modules folder** is not in your **PATH**.

Please run below command to append your **npm module folder** into `PATH`:

```
setx path "%APPDATA%\npm;%path%"
```

Then you should be able to execute `vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc`.

Comment: This worked, but I had to reboot after running setx before it took effect.

Comment: I had to run the above command, restart my computer, AND kill the terminal in VS Code; then after opening a new terminal and rerunning the command it worked.

Comment: No reboot required. Killing the terminal, restarting VCS did the trick for me.

Comment: zsh: command not found: setx

Comment: @KonstantinVahrushev I'm afraid you need to install and set **setx** as windows environmental variable, then you can run setx command

Answer (score 96):

Try to: `npx vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc`

Comment: I ultimately got it to work with: npx vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc -TargetConfig "%USERPROFILE%\.npmrc"

Comment: worked like charm

Comment: This worked very well, but some explanation (perhaps a sentence with a link to more info in official docs) would be appreciated.

Comment: @MarcL., according to official docs (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npx), npx allows us to run an arbitrary command from an npm package (either one installed locally, or fetched remotely), in a similar context as running it via npm run. 
So in our case  it basically allows us to execute vsts-npm-auth in the context of npm avoiding aforementioned error as npm knows the reference or path to vsts-npm-auth command executable

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
npm install -g vsts-npm-auth
```

and then restart the terminal session (it is important)

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio (VS) Code try killing and restarting the terminal session and running again.

[Image: VS Code terminal trash icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWM0P.png)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, using force did it for me.

```
npx vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc -F
```